# Draw and edit polygon nodes on gmap with retrieve points as arrary over Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps

Im creating a location base boundaries to mark the delivery area.    [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple](http://%C2%A0%20%C2%A0https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

As the above reference or other tutorials have very less info. Please suggest a reference to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution found http://jsbin.com/ajimur/10. It uses a function that adds a delete button to the passed in polygon.

Don't forget to add the google maps library http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=GB&libraries=drawing

```js
var G = google.maps;
var zoom = 7;
var centerPoint = new G.LatLng(45.5, -100.5);


$(function() {
  // create options object
  var myOptions = {
    center: centerPoint,
    zoom: zoom,
    mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  
  // create map with options
  var map = new G.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], myOptions);
  
  addPolygon(map);
});


function addPolygon(map){
  var paths = [
          new G.LatLng(45, -100),
          new G.LatLng(45.5, -99.5),
          new G.LatLng(46, -100),
          new G.LatLng(46, -101),
          new G.LatLng(45, -101)
  ];

  poly = new G.Polygon({
          clickable: false,
          paths: paths,
          map: map
  }); 

  poly.setEditable(true);

  addDeleteButton(poly, 'http://i.imgur.com/RUrKV.png');
}


function addDeleteButton(poly, imageUrl) {
  var path = poly.getPath();
  path["btnDeleteClickHandler"] = {};
  path["btnDeleteImageUrl"] = imageUrl;
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(),'set_at',pointUpdated);
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(),'insert_at',pointUpdated);
}

function pointUpdated(index) {
  var path = this;
  var btnDelete = getDeleteButton(path.btnDeleteImageUrl);
  
  if(btnDelete.length === 0) 
  {
    var undoimg = $("img[src$='http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/undo_poly.png']");
    
    undoimg.parent().css('height', '21px !important');
    undoimg.parent().parent().append('<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 27px;top:21px;"><img src="' + path.btnDeleteImageUrl + '" class="deletePoly" style="height:auto; width:auto; position: absolute; left:0;"/></div>');
    
    // now get that button back again!
    btnDelete = getDeleteButton(path.btnDeleteImageUrl);
    btnDelete.hover(function() { $(this).css('left', '-30px'); return false;}, 
                    function() { $(this).css('left', '0px'); return false;});
    btnDelete.mousedown(function() { $(this).css('left', '-60px'); return false;});
  }
  
  // if we've already attached a handler, remove it
  if(path.btnDeleteClickHandler) 
    btnDelete.unbind('click', path.btnDeleteClickHandler);
    
  // now add a handler for removing the passed in index
  path.btnDeleteClickHandler = function() {
    path.removeAt(index); 
    return false;
  };
  btnDelete.click(path.btnDeleteClickHandler);
}

function getDeleteButton(imageUrl) {
  return  $("img[src$='" + imageUrl + "']");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps example</title>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=GB&libraries=drawing">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. Let me check this. Also is possible to get those values?

Comment: Why my question has minus rate?